# Need help understanding 'no attribute' error message in Google Natural Language API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-natural-language

**Situation**

I'm trying to run Google's Cloud NLP sentiment analysis on a text field pulled from the Twitter API with Tweepy and then turned into a pandas Dataframe. That Dataframe has a text field called `text`, which is the tweet content on which I'd like to run the sentiment analysis.

This is my reference code:

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries

**Expectation**

I was expecting this process to run sentiment analysis on the `text` field in my Dataframe, returning values for `sentiment score` and `sentiment magnitude`. Next step would be to then send those values back into the dataframe.

**What I've tried**

Below is the code I'm running.

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import language_v1


# Instantiates a client
client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()

# The text to analyze
text = dfTWEENGAGE.loc[:,"text"]
document = language_v1.Document(
    content=text, type_=language_v1.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT
)

# Detects the sentiment of the text
sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(
    request={"document": document}
).document_sentiment

print("Text: {}".format(text))
print("Sentiment: {}, {}".format(sentiment.score, sentiment.magnitude))
```

The only thing I've changed from the example is:

`text = dfTWEENGAGE.loc[:,"text"]`

… to find the `text` column in the `dfTWEENGAGE` Dataframe.

**Results**

It's returning the following error message:

`AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.language_v1' has no attribute 'Document'`

This is confusing to me because I'm on the documentation and seeing the 'Document' attribute here:

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.language.v1#google.cloud.language.v1.Document

The code following `Document` also matches the API documentation: `.Type.PLAIN_TEXT`

So I'd greatly appreciate any insights or explanations regarding the Document attribute and what I might be doing wrong here.

dsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update your `type_=language_v1.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT` into `type_=language_v1.types.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT` and your code will run successfully. Please see this api [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/language/latest/language_v1/types.html#google.cloud.language_v1.types.Document) for more information.

In addition, make sure that you have the updated **google-cloud-language library** by running this `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-language`

Below is my testing using your code and using `u"Hello, world!"` as my sample text input.

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import language_v1


# Instantiates a client
client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()

# The text to analyze
text = u"Hello, world!"
document = language_v1.Document(
    content=text, type_=language_v1.types.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT
)

# Detects the sentiment of the text
sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(
    request={"document": document}
).document_sentiment

print("Text: {}".format(text))
print("Sentiment: {}, {}".format(sentiment.score, sentiment.magnitude))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Scott B. 

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I'm running your exact code but getting the following message:

`WARNING: The following packages were previously imported in this runtime:
  [google]
You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.`

That's the tail of a much longer message that starts: 

`ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed.`

After I restart the runtime, the NL process hangs on this line:

`request={"document": document}`

Comment: I figured out the problem. My authentication wasn't complete, but I didn't see any related error messages, but I guess that's why it hung up on `request`